# Is it possible to instruct PHP to use postfix configuration in php.ini?

Tags: php, phpmailer, ubuntu-14.04, postfix-mta

Is it possible to configure PHP to send email using the configuration set for postfix?

WordPress (via PHPMailer) relies on these settings to be correct in php.ini:

```
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
mail.log = /var/log/mail.log
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

Postfix is configured to use Google's SMTP server and confirmed as working at the OS (Ubuntu 14.04) level

PHPMailer fails (from WordPress) with the error:

> Could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: This combination works out of the box for me. Does `/usr/sbin/sendmail` exist? Do you have separate php.ini files for cli and web server SAPIs? You could try using SMTP to localhost, which is the recommended way of talking to a local postfix instance, since it's faster than calling a sendmail binary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sendmail does exist at that path. There are separate php.ini files - same settings in both. Its php-fpm if that makes a difference. I am restarting php-fpm rather than apache (but have tried both). I've now tried the SMTP settings too - same error.

Comment: You can't be using SMTP if you're getting that error as it only occurs if you call mail()

Comment: Thanks - you were right. There was another ini file overriding any settings I made to php.ini (see my answer). Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out because I was using php-fpm, there were settings I wasn't aware were set living in /etc/php5/mods-available/zzzz_custom.ini.

Adding the sendmail path to that file worked for me :

```
sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```